# add variable to actions/functions across different files (woocommerce)

Tags: functions, actions, woocommerce-offtopic, variables

I'm using woocommerce which is working fine.
On the template for the related products for example you'll find this:

```
<?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
```

This calls the loop-start.php.  Is there any possibility to add some variables to this function which I can call in the loop-start.php?

for example: woocommerce_product_loop_start($test)

And in loop-start.php I can do "echo $test".  I also tried with global variables but it didn't work out.

Same goes for the content loop call "wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );".  Can I add some variables on this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Anything that loads a template in WordPress is ultimately an `include()` or `require()` and only the variables in the caller function scope (and global scope of course) are passed on to the included file:

```
function foo() {
    $bar = 1;
    include( '/path/to/template.php' );
}

$baz = 2;
foo();

// template.php:
echo $bar; // 1
echo $baz; // undefined
```

So to make something like you described work, you'll have to change the behavior of Core's `load_template()` function which performs the actual `require()`. But there are other ways. Here are a couple:

Global scope (nobody likes global scope):

```
$GLOBALS['myvar'] = 1; // will be accessible from anywhere
```

Static class properties:

```
class My_Class {
    public static $myvar;
}

My_Class::$myvar = 1;
```

`My_Class::$myvar` will be accessible in your templates, provided that you declared the class and changed the static variable prior to loading your template. It's almost like using the global scope but cleaner.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can not add parameters to the function but you can create your own. When a "core" function is under a `function_exists` (and it's the case of loop_start and loop_end) you can override the main function with yours in a plugin or in the theme functions.php.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start' ) ) {

/**
 * Output the start of a product loop. By default this is a UL.
 *
 * @param bool $echo
 * @return string
 */
    function woocommerce_product_loop_start( $echo = true ) {
        ob_start();
        $GLOBALS['woocommerce_loop']['loop'] = 0;
        wc_get_template( 'loop/loop-start.php' );
        if ( $echo )
            echo ob_get_clean();
        else
            return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this function only looking for the template file for the loop start. So there's an easiest way to do it:

You can use the template hierarchy to load your own file. This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php, add a do_action to retrieve your parameter and make the job.